# matrices whose entries $a_{ij}$ are groups

Tags: reference-request

Has there been any work done on square matrices whose entries $a_{ij}$ are groups? (and with the operations below?)

For instance: let  $\mathbb{F},\mathbb{G},\mathbb{H},\mathbb{K}$,
$\mathbb{A},\mathbb{B},\mathbb{J},\mathbb{W}$ be groups, and let $\oplus$ denote group direct sum and $*$ denote free product, and for a $2\times 2$ "group matrix" define the operations$\mathbf{Y}$ and $\mathbf{U}$:

$$\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
\mathbb{F} & \mathbb{G} \\
\mathbb{H} & \mathbb{K} \end{array} \right]
\mathbf{Y}
\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
\mathbb{A} & \mathbb{B} \\
\mathbb{J} & \mathbb{W} \end{array} \right]
=
\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
\mathbb{F}\oplus\mathbb{A} & \mathbb{G}\oplus\mathbb{B} \\
\mathbb{H}\oplus\mathbb{J} & \mathbb{K}\oplus\mathbb{W} \end{array} \right]
$$

$$
\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
\mathbb{F} & \mathbb{G} \\
\mathbb{H} & \mathbb{K} \end{array} \right]
\mathbf{U}
\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
\mathbb{A} & \mathbb{B} \\
\mathbb{J} & \mathbb{W} \end{array} \right]
=
\left[ \begin{array}{cc}
(\mathbb{F}*\mathbb{A})\oplus(\mathbb{G}*\mathbb{J}) & (\mathbb{F}*\mathbb{B})\oplus(\mathbb{G}*\mathbb{W}) \\
(\mathbb{H}*\mathbb{A})\oplus(\mathbb{K}*\mathbb{J}) & (\mathbb{H}*\mathbb{B})\oplus(\mathbb{K}*\mathbb{W}) \end{array} \right]
$$

Comment: Well, I haven't seen any work on this. Is there any particular reason you ask?

Comment: @TannerL.Swett: google searches involving the terms "group" and "matrices" turn up a lot of representation theory stuff, and that's not what I'm asking about.

Comment: @deoxygerbe: Echoing Tanner, is there a reason why you want to study such objects? Are you interested in the properties of such matrices?

Comment: Note that in the category of groups coproducts (which are given by free product) don't distribute over products. For example $\mathbb{Z}*(\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z})$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z}$ as the ranks of their abelianizations differ. Hence, $U$ doesn't distribute over $Y,$ which makes the two operations seem algebraically unrelated. In my mind, this raises doubts as to whether someone would find such objects interesting.